# How to properly configure external nuget package source with credentials?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have an external nuget package source in my project which I added in Visual Studio 2017 by the `Package Manager Settings`. I can install the packages properly but when I click on `publish` (it's a dotnet core console app). I get this error status:

> 2>Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://***.azure.com/*****/system.servicemodel.duplex/index.json'.
> 2>Response status code does not indicate success: 40

Blockquote

1 (Unauthorized).

I searched a solution which says to add the credentials using the `cmd`, but when I try to execute the command to add I get this error message from the cmd:

> The name specified has already been added to the list of available package sources. Please provide a unique name.

So I need to remove the package source from Visual Studio (using the Package Manager Settings) and after I remove the package source the `cmd` command works, but then I don't have access anymore to the external packages in Visual Studio (because I removed it to be possible to add from the command line).

How can I fix that?

EDIT:
The cmd syntax is this:

```
nuget.exe sources add -name MyExternalSource -source https://***/nuget/v3/index.json -username nugetUser -password MyToken
```

Comment: Before moving on, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior check where exactly your user credentials are stored. Also try to use `dotnet publish` to generate deployment binaries which might give you a better error message than Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you built the project successfully before the publish? If your situation is build fine while publish failed, maybe you can try rebuild the project and make sure referenced assemblies are copied to output folder, then publish the project.

Answer (score 0):

It needs Identity when pushing or consuming packages through a Azure Devops feed.

I think you don't need to use command like `nuget.exe sources Add -Name "TestNuget" -Source "https://xxx/nuget/v3/index.json"`, since it is used to manage the package sources in `Nuget.config` file instead of solving the **Unauthorized** issue. See [sources command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-sources).

> I get this error status:
>
> 2>Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source
>   'https://***.azure.com/*****/system.servicemodel.duplex/index.json'.
>   2>Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

Most of the time, I met this kind of message when using [Self-Contained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd) deploy mode. But actually the publish can succeed in my machine with message like this:

[image]

(I think the publish also succeeds in your side, in this situation I think you can ignore it or publish the project the second time with same PublishProfile, the error message would go away)

Also you can publish the project with [Framework-dependent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#framework-dependent-executables-fde) mode after builds the project successfully.

If the publish failed:

1.And if your publish fails with that message, in my opinion you can remove the `referenced packages` by `Nuget Package Manager UI`, and remove the `Feed Url` from `Package Sources UI`.

2.Then restart VS and `re-set` the Feed Url in `Package Sources Setting`. No need to use command-line, use VS2017 UI and re-add the package after re-set the Package Source.

3.When you search the package from new-set feed like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-nuget?view=azure-devops#consume-packages), it will pop up an **Identity Window** which requires you to enter account and password, and then you're now **authorized**. After that you can find, consume the package in your project, and publish it successfully. Hope it helps.